# Showing syntax error while executing function via code

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, ado.net

Following is my `Function` created in `PostgreSQL`

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcInsert(iacid int,islno int,idate date) RETURNS int AS
$$
declare id_val int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GTAB83 (acid,slno,orderdte) VALUES (iacid,islno,idate) RETURNING orderid into id_val;
return id_val;
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and my code to execute the above function using `vb.net` is

```
        Dim myCmd As PgSqlCommand = New PgSqlCommand("funcInsert", Myconnstr)
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("iacid", PgSqlType.Int).Value = cboCust.SelectedValue
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("islno", PgSqlType.Int).Value = txtOrderNO.Text
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("idate", PgSqlType.Int).Value = txtDate.Text
        myCmd.ExecuteScalar()
        trans.Commit()
```

the error is

[image]

Comment: `LANGUAGE plpgsql` - don't quote the language name (not the answer to primary q.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the command with a `SELECT` statement.

```
Dim myCmd As PgSqlCommand = New PgSqlCommand("SELECT funcInsert(@iacid, @islno, @idate)", Myconnstr)
```